# Symfony Entity one-to-one relation

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity

Can you look at the relationship between entities, unfortunately all the time is not working properly. I will be grateful for the help. This is a relation 1 to 1.

User Entity

```
 /**
    *
    * @ORM\Column(type="string")
    *
    * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Structure", mappedBy="user")
    */
    protected $structure;
```

Structure Entity

```
/**
* @var string
*
* @ORM\Column(name="user", type="string", length=50, unique=false)
* @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="structure")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
private $user;
```

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: After sending a table from the controller to twig, the structure column does not exist

Comment: Try to remove @ORM\Column of both sides...relations itself don't have column..Regards 
Check http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-bidirectional

Comment: @Albeis Bull's-eye :) Now works perfectly. Thank you and all for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one ...

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", 
* inversedBy="structure")
*/
private $user;



 /**
 *@ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Structure",mappedBy="user",cascade={"persist","remove"})
 */
private $structure;
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Albeis in a comment:

> Try to remove `@ORM\Column` of both sides...relations itself don't
>   have column..Regards Check
>   http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-bidirectional

This solved my problem. The issue was about to remove @ORM\Column of both sides. Thanks for help.

Comment: Glad to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `mappedBy` with [@OneToOne](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-onetoone). You should use `inversedBy` on both sides.

Comment: Thank you @Paulpro. I do the changes, but nothing happened. Still showing up "Impossible to access an attribute ("username") on a string variable ("5")".

Comment: Maybe the problem is that the Users table comes from FOSUserBundle?

Comment: in twig:{{ structure[1].user.username }} this line generates error

Comment: and in the controller:

Comment: $structureRepo=$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('APManagerBundle:Structure');
        $structure=$structureRepo->findAll();

Comment: First, `mappedBy` is a valid attribute for this annotation, second, using `inversedBy` on both side does not make any sense at all.

Comment: @DonCallisto I also think that mappedBy is correct, but I try this and nothing happend.

Answer (score 0):

```
    /**
    * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Core\UserBundle\Entity\Profile", mappedBy="user")
    */
    private $profile;


    /**
    * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Core\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="profile")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id",onDelete="CASCADE")
    */
    private $user;
```

user_id inside profile entity. 
 if you set onDelete="CASCADE", if you delete user, profile will deleting automatically by mysql.

Comment: $structureRepo=$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('APManagerBundle:Structure');         $structure=$structureRepo->findAll();

Comment: i read below comments. Why you try {{ structure[1].user.username }} ?  You can use foreach or  {{ structure.first.user.username }}. And error in controller  or twig ?

Comment: By calling specific numbers in the array it works fine, but for sure I also tried looping - that does not change anything. The error is displayed on the Twig side and I do not know why it treats the mapped id number as string ..

Comment: Impossible to access an attribute ("username") on a string variable ("5").

Comment: You can try {{ dump(structure) }} on twig or dump($structure); exit; on controller  (if symfony > 2.7) for see your object.